# S3 Or EC2 which one's bandwidth will be used while serving image through a proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, bandwidth

My server is in **AWS EC2** and I am using **S3** for image storage for my website, which is pretty much an image driven site. Also my site is being served over **https**.

Now the scenario is like that on my site any one can upload image or any one can post a third party link. As those third party links can be from any **http or https** site, so I decided to make a proxy for links.

Also for uploaded images, I want to show the images only to the owner of the image. To implement it also I have decided to serve those images through a proxy.

My Technology Stack is

1. PHP (YII)
2. Mysql
3. Apache
4. Node js

**Now my questions are**

**1. If I use such proxy image server, then whose bandwidth will be used? Is it EC2 Or S3?**

**2. Is there any other way to solve my problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a proxy will use the proxy's EC2 bandwidth, not the S3 bandwidth.

If you don't want to use a proxy, you can use signed URLs to control access to the files on S3.  You can provide a signed link to the content on S3.  Then only people to whom you sent the link will be able to see the file on S3 (although nothing is preventing them from sharing that link).

Comment: But if I use signed url it will not prevent the unauthorized users from from watching images. Like right now what Gmail does with attachment. What is your opinion regarding usage of amazon's Security Token Service ?

Comment: N. B. The proxy will use *both* EC2 and S3 bandwidth if the EC2 instance and the S3 bucket are not in the same AWS region.  Also, yes, signed links can be shared, but they can also have extremely short expiration times, making sharing highly unlikely (and you can discover sharing attempts in the S3 logs, if you turn those on).